# How can "t = foo(); with t" be different from "with foo()"?

Tags: python-3.x, cpython

I'm testing a program transformation tool. It's causing one of the CPython tests to fail, but I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Here's a minified version of one of the tests in test_sax.py from the CPython test suite, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_sax.py#L143 . This snippet writes an XML file and then reads it back in the wrong encoding. This causes `xml.sax.parse` to fail and raise an exception. When it does so, the file it opened should be leaked. The garbage collector detects this leak. The following test checks this behavior:

```
def test_parse_bytes(self):
    make_xml_file(self.data, 'iso-8859-1', None)
    with support.check_warnings(('unclosed file', ResourceWarning)) :
        with self.assertRaises(SAXException):
            self.check_parse(TESTFN)
        gc.collect()
```

My program transformation tool changes this snippet to something like the following:

```
def test_parse_bytes(self):
    make_xml_file(self.data, 'iso-8859-1', None)
    with support.check_warnings(('unclosed file', ResourceWarning)) :
        t = self.assertRaises(SAXException)
        with t:
            self.check_parse(TESTFN)
        gc.collect()
```

According to what I know about Python, these too snippets should be absolutely identical. When I step through in the debugger, I can't tell what they're doing differently. Yet, somehow, the latter snippet causes the file to not be leaked, and hence causes the test to fail. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet, the result of `self.assertRaises(SAXException)` is out of scope when `gc.collect()` is called, so it's garbage and is guaranteed to be collected; in the second snippet, the reference `t` is still in scope, so it doesn't. There's some path of references from `t` to the file handle--perhaps it contains a reference to the exception that was raised, and the exception contains a reference to the file. As a result, the file isn't garbage when `gc.collect()` gets called, so it doesn't get auto-closed. The outer `with` block then checks for unclosed files, and finds a file which, while it is garbage and would be closed if the garbage collector ran again with `t` out of scope, is nevertheless still open.

Comment: Added a "del t" statement, and the test passed. Confirmed. Thanks Jim!